# Nesting case statements

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, case

I'm trying to fathom out a query to say when today falls within this financial year (1/11 - 31/10), Run this set of Case statements, but when today is in next financial year run the next set etc...

I've tried nesting the CASE statements but not working.  Below is just to explain what I am trying to do..

Thanks for looking!

```
IF Getdate() Between '2012-11-01 00:00' AND '2013-10-31 23:59' -- is it this year?

THEN
        CASE
         WHEN B.saledate Between '2011-11-01 00:00' AND Getdate()-365 THEN 'Yes'
         WHEN B.saledate Between '2012-11-01 00:00' AND Getdate() THEN 'Yes'
        Else 'No'
        AS 'Financial year to date',
        END

IF Getdate() Between '2013-11-01 00:00' AND '2014-10-31 23:59' -- is it this year yet?
THEN
        CASE
         WHEN B.Created Between '2011-11-01 00:00' AND Getdate()-730 THEN 'Yes'
         WHEN B.Created Between '2012-11-01 00:00' AND Getdate()-365 THEN 'Yes'
         WHEN B.Created Between '2013-11-01 00:00' AND Getdate() THEN 'Yes'
        Else 'No'
        AS 'Financial year to date',
        END

END
```

Comment: I have added a solution on how to get the financial year of each row. If you explain wht you want to do with it, i can provide some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, but the key to this wes financial year to date, not just the financial year.

Solved as per below.  It does mean adding a new blocks each year but that's where I'm at for now.

```
CASE
         WHEN 
         Getdate() Between '2012-11-01 00:00' AND '2013-10-31 23:59' AND
         (
         cast(convert(char(11), B.Created, 10) as datetime) Between '2009-11-01 00:00' AND (cast(getdate()-1096 as date)) OR
         cast(convert(char(11), B.Created, 10) as datetime) Between '2010-11-01 00:00' AND (cast(getdate()-731 as date)) OR
         cast(convert(char(11), B.Created, 10) as datetime) Between '2011-11-01 00:00' AND (cast(getdate()-366 as date)) OR
         cast(convert(char(11), B.Created, 10) as datetime) Between '2012-11-01 00:00' AND (cast(getdate() as date))
         )
         THEN 'Yes' 

         WHEN Getdate() Between '2013-11-01 00:00' AND '2014-10-31 23:59' AND
         (
         cast(convert(char(11), B.Created, 10) as datetime) Between '2009-11-01 00:00' AND (cast(getdate()-1461 as date)) OR
         cast(convert(char(11), B.Created, 10) as datetime) Between '2010-11-01 00:00' AND (cast(getdate()-1096 as date)) OR
         cast(convert(char(11), B.Created, 10) as datetime) Between '2011-11-01 00:00' AND (cast(getdate()-731 as date)) OR
         cast(convert(char(11), B.Created, 10) as datetime) Between '2012-11-01 00:00' AND (cast(getdate()-366 as date)) OR
         cast(convert(char(11), B.Created, 10) as datetime) Between '2013-11-01 00:00' AND (cast(getdate() as date))
         )
         THEN 'Yes'

Else 'No'
END
AS 'Financial year to date',
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you will end up with ever increasing code.

To get a certain fiscal year oyu may try that:

```
DECLARE @DateToCheck AS DATETIME

SET @DateToCheck = '20130101'

SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(mm,-10,@DateToCheck))
```

So if you have a table `Transactions` with a DateTime field `TransactionDate`

```
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(mm,-10,TransactionDate))
FROM   Transactions
```

will get you the fiscal year of each transaction.